# コミュニティ広告（２０１５年）

Tags: 討議, コミュニティ広告

#### コミュニティ広告とは？

コミュニティ広告はメインサイトの右側に表示される広告で、ここで広告の審査を行います。提案者がここに広告画像を投稿し、コミュニティの投票を経て、広告として表示されるようになります。

#### 広告の内容に何を入れるべきですか？

当コミュニティのユーザーや日本のプログラマーに役立つ情報が中心になります。例えば・・・

- 当サイトのTwitter
- 日本語で書かれた技術ブログやウェブサイト
- プログラミング関連のイベントや勉強会、カンファレンス
- オープンソースプロジェクト
- その他いろいろ

#### 広告の期間は？

毎年12月に全ての広告をリセットします。リソースやサービスは終了・移転することがありますし、イベント情報も古くなってしまうからです。また、新しい広告を載せるきっかけにもなります。

リセット後同じ広告を提案しても構いませんが、毎年同じ広告ではインパクトが弱くなります。広告の文章・画像を毎年更新するとより効果があるでしょう。

#### 広告の提案はどのように行いますか？

この質問に回答として投稿します。広告の表示はシステムで自動的に処理されるため、必ず以下のルールを守ってください。

1. バナーを提案する回答は以下の形式に沿っている必要があります。

   ```
   [![マウスオーバーの言葉][1]][2] 

   [1]: http://画像のurl 
   [2]: http://リンク先のurl
   ```

これ以外に**文章を書いてはいけません**。疑問点・指摘がある場合、コメントを利用してください。

2. 回答先の質問には [コミュニティ広告](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9f%e3%83%a5%e3%83%8b%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3%e5%ba%83%e5%91%8a) が必要です。このタグの付いた質問に対する回答が広告として表示されるほか、回答欄に上記テンプレートが自動挿入されます。

#### バナー画像の仕様

- 画像サイズは **220 x 250 ピクセル** のみ
- 普段の回答と同じように当サイトの機能でアップロードしてください(imgur)
- ファイル形式は GIF または PNG
- アニメーションGIFは使えません
- ファイルサイズは 150 KB 以内

#### 広告が表示される条件

投票の結果、**最低スコア**（現在6点）を超えたものがメインサイトに表示されます。

上記の最低スコアを超えている広告は[ここで](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/1994)確認できます。

Comment: 「コミュニティ広告」の目的って何でしょう？どういった利用シーンを想定したものなのか、あまり理解できませんでした。例えば英語版SOやSE他サイトの具体例などがあるでしょうか。

Comment: @yohjp 英語版SOでは、「[Open Source Advertising](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015)」（オープンソースのプロジェクトを広告できる仕組み）があります。SEのコミュニティでは、[コミュニティ広告](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/639/community-promotion-ads-2015)があります。最初の目的は[このブログ（英語）にあります](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/)。単純に、当サイトのスペースを利用して、プログラマーに便利なプロジェクトを支援したいです。プログラマーのためのサイトですので、皆様への小さな恩返しです。

Comment: 広告が表示されているのを見たことがないのですが、どういう条件で表示されるのでしょう？ あるいはAdBlockの類が入っていると表示されないというようなことはありますか？

Comment: @holywise いつも現れるわけは無いです。一部のビューで表示されていますが、相当稀です。一つの広告を２４時間中に見続けたら、すぐ諦めるので、頻度は低めにしています。

Answer (score 7):

[image: freeCodeCampTokyo]

Comment: 無料でJavaScriptを利用したWeb開発が学べるオープンソースプロジェクト [freeCodeCamp](http://freecodecamp.com/) のTokyoコミュニティです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score -1):

[image: 当コミュニティを成長しよう！]

Comment: これを適当に作りましたので、指摘よろしくお願いします。