# コミュニティ広告を掲載しますか？もし必要な場合、どんな種類を希望しますか？

Tags: 討議, コミュニティ広告

翻訳をしてくれた[@cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)に感謝します。

---

多くの Stack Exchange サイトは非常に人気があります (つまり、多くのページビューがあります)。ページビューの一部を有料広告として利用していますが、[サイトを過負荷にすることなく](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/25/responsible-advertising-feed-a-programmer/)、[慎重に](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/25/responsible-advertising-feed-a-programmer/)行っています。 有料広告枠は少し設けてありますが、まだまだ広告枠には余裕があります。

#### [今年はスタック・オーバーフローにおいて無料の広告枠をコミュニティに提供できることを嬉しく思います！](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/31/community-promotion-ads/)

あなたの考えを共有してください:

1. サイトにコミュニティ広告を掲載しますか、それ無しの方がいいですか？
2. サイトにコミュニティ広告が必要な場合、どんな種類の広告にする必要がありますか？

#### コミュニティ広告の種類

すべての Stack Exchange コミュニティでは、以下を促進することが推奨されます:

- サイトごとのメタに関するコミュニティによる社会活動。
- サイトに関連したフリー/オープンソースのツールとアプリケーション。
- ユーザーにとって役立つ集会またはその他のイベント。
- コミュニティが本当に興味を持つものであればどんなものでも。

唯一の例外サイトがあります - Stack Overflow (英語版) においては追加の制限があります: [広告は、実際のオープンソースコードを作成するプログラマーの参加と貢献を募るものであるべきです](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/19/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/)。私たちのサイトは英語版の Stack Overflow にかなり近いです。同様の制限が必要かもしれません…それともそうすべきではないでしょうか？

どう思いますか？コミュニティ広告を希望しますか？もしそうなら、スタック・オーバーフローにおいてどんな種類のコミュニティ広告を掲載する必要がありますか？あなたの考えを共有してください！

なお、Stack Exchange 社では編集管理を行い、サイトでの掲載に適さない広告を禁止する権利を留保します。

Comment: 「コミュニティ広告」についての概要は [過去の投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1994) も参考にしてください。

Comment: 広告をつけるとして、それが掲載される期間はどのくらいでしょうか？　If we have community ads, how long will them run?

Comment: @nekketsuuu 過去の投稿では [毎年12月にリセットする](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1994) という発言もありましたが、[去年作成したバナー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2960) は今でも時折表示されています。 / 期日の設定されたイベント告知でない限り、新しいバナーができるまでは継続しての掲載でもいいのかもしれません。

Answer (score 4):

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにもそれなりのアクセスがありますし、OSS コミュニティなどのプログラミング・コミュニティの発信の場となるのは嬉しいことと思います。

実際に OSS への貢献を促すような広告に絞るべきかどうかについて、私自身はこの制限はそこまで要らないかなと思っています。OSS を使ってみようという広告でも、あるいは特定のソフトウェアに依拠しないコミュニティ（[プログラミング言語処理系 Slack](https://prog-lang-sys-ja-slack.github.io/wiki/)、[インフラ勉強会](https://wiki.infra-workshop.tech/)、などなど）の広告でも、良いのではないかと思っています。

英語版 Stack Overflow の[説明](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394409/5989200)を読むと、この制限は貢献を必要としている OSS に人を集めるためのもののようです。なぜこのような目的に絞っているか分からなかったので少し考えてみたのですが、日本語版においてはまだこれに絞る理由が思いつきませんでした。