# コミュニティ広告の案を募集しています (2020年)

Tags: 討議, コミュニティ広告

翻訳をしてくれた[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)、[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)、[@cubick](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)、[@Yuki Inoue](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue)に感謝します。

**要約**：
OSS プロジェクトに関するバナー広告をスタック・オーバーフローに掲載できます！
この質問への「回答」として候補を投稿してください。

---

新しい企画をご紹介します。「オープンソースプロジェクトに対する投票ベースの無料広告」企画です！

投票に基づき、無料で[オープンソース・プロジェクトの広告](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/)を作成するチャンスです。オープンソース・プロジェクトの画像広告を作成し、この質問への回答として（規定のフォーマットで）投稿すると、スタック・オーバーフローに広告が表示されます。

（訳注: [元ブログ](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) からの翻訳抜粋）

> Stack Overflow では熱心なプログラマーによって多くのページビューを集めていますが、広告の掲載枠にはいくつかの余裕がある状態です。
>
> この余剰枠を無駄にするのではなく、プログラマーの支援が必要なオープンソース・プロジェクトを宣伝するためのスペースとして使用することができれば、プログラミング・コミュニティにとってもメリットがあると考え、「コミュニティ広告」の案を募集することにしました。

---

### 広告の要件

[以前の議論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3300/78)や英語版Stack Overflowでの経験から、次の要件で開始することにしました。

**実際のソースコードを書くプログラマーの参加と貢献を募る広告**でなければなりません。何らかの製品がたまたまオープンソースであるからといって、その製品をただ宣伝するだけの広告は掲載できません。この広告の目的は、コーディングやその他のプログラミングに関すること（ドキュメント、コードのレビュー、問題の修正など）にコントリビュートしてくれるプログラマーを見つけることです。

実際に広告として掲載されるためには、次のルールに従った回答を投稿する**必要があります**。

### 回答のテンプレート

```
[![画像が表示されない場合の代替テキスト。][1]][2]

  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

**投稿の本文には何も追加しないでください**。説明などを追加したい場合は、コメントに残してください。

### 画像の要件

- 作成する画像は**300 x 250 ピクセル**、または高DPIの場合はその2倍でなければなりません。

  - 標準の画像アップローダー（imgur）を介してホスト。
  - GIFまたはPNGである必要があります。
  - アニメーションGIFは不可。
  - 絶対最大サイズは**150 KB**。
  - 背景（の一部）が白の場合は1 pxの境界線が必要です。画像が高DPIの場合は2 px。
  - 広告のテキストは日本語のみ。

最終的に広告として採用されると、次のURLにて出力がプレビューできるようになります。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### スコアしきい値

回答が上記URLによって提供され、スタック・オーバーフローで表示されるには **最小スコアしきい値** (現在は6) を満たしている必要があります。次のページでは現在の基準を満たしている広告を全て確認することができます。

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/3333

### 参考:

英語版でも同様の取り組みを定期的に行っているため、実際の提案や結果の参考になるでしょう。[1H 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394409), [2H 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386746)

この URL をリロードすると色々広告の例を見ることができ、参考になります： https://stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

Comment: この広告は、掲載が始まってからどのくらいの期間掲載され続ける予定ですか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 通常は1年間実行されます。 コミュニティが望むなら、私たちは何か他のことができます。

Comment: 取り組み自体は良いものだと思いますが、画像を用意しなければいけない点がハードルになっているかもしれません。 主に集まっているのはプログラマーであって、デザイナーでは無いので。